# Event Receiver trouble in permission changed

Tags: event-receivers

I have the following problem with this code:

```
    public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemUpdating(properties);

        const string fieldInternalNameWrt = "UserWrt";
        const string fieldInternalNameRdr = "UserRdr";

        SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
        SPUser userWrt = null;
        SPUser userRdr = null;

        if (properties.AfterProperties[fieldInternalNameWrt] != null)
        {
            string userValueWrt = properties.AfterProperties[fieldInternalWrt].ToString();
            userWrt = GetSPUserFromId(properties.ListTitle, userValueWrt, fieldInternalWrt, properties);
        }

        if (properties.AfterProperties[fieldInternalNameRdr] != null)
        {
            string userValueRdr = properties.AfterProperties[fieldInternalNameRdr].ToString();
            userRdr = GetSPUserFromId(properties.ListTitle, userValueRdr, fieldInternalNameRdr, properties);
        }

        if (userWrt == null && userRdr == null)
            return;

        SPRoleAssignment roleAssignmentWrt = null;
        if (userWrt != null)
        {
            roleAssignmentWrt = new SPRoleAssignment(userWrt);
            var roleDefinition = properties.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);
            roleAssignmentWrt.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
        }

        SPRoleAssignment roleAssignmentRdr = null;
        if (userRdr != null)
        {
            roleAssignmentRdr = new SPRoleAssignment(userRdr);
            var roleDefinition = properties.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
            roleAssignmentRdr.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
        }

        try
        {
            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;

            lock (_thisLock)
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
                {
                    item.BreakRoleInheritance(false);

                    foreach (SPRoleAssignment assignment in item.RoleAssignments)
                    {
                        assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.RemoveAll();
                        assignment.Update();
                    }

                    if (roleAssignmentWrt != null)
                        item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignmentWrt);

                    if (roleAssignmentRdr != null)
                        item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignmentRdr);

                    item.Update();
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
        }
    }

    public static SPUser GetSPUserFromId(string listName, string currentValue, string nameField, SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPFieldUserValue fieldValue;

        using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
        {
            var userField = (SPFieldUser)web.Lists[listName].Fields.GetField(nameField);
            fieldValue = (SPFieldUserValue)userField.GetFieldValue(currentValue);
        }

        return fieldValue.User;
    }
```

the item's permissions was changed but I receive the following error!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1lgn.jpg[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1lgn.jpg)

anyone knows why?

Comment: it is impossible to read the attached screenshot. Please fix by adding the text as formattet code.
Also remember to have EventFiringEnabled in a try/finally or you wont get it enabled again if your code breaks.
Also please try to describe what you are trying to do, what works and what doesnt. In other words: help us help you :-)
Reading our [faq] might help you in formulating your question in a way that allows us to help you in the best way possible [How To ask](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#link-howtoask)

Comment: You get this, when specyfic item from the list isn't exists. Somthing doesn't exist on which You calling.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of comments:

- As @AndersRask mentioned in the comment put the restore of EventFiringEnabled in a finally block
- Your current use of `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` isn't doing anything except wasting resources. In order for it to allow more than the current user you need to allocate a new SPSite + SPWeb + SPList + SPListItem
- My guess is that the lock also is completely useless
- You should use SPListItem.SystemUpdate when doing changes behind the users back
- If you don't want us to see the name of the document and user then you should also strike it out in the blue band

Comment: ok I expanded my code and I changed the image :)

Comment: have you guys others suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried to switch to `SystemUpdate` instead of `Update`? And if you're not using `lock` and `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` for anything remove them.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with ItemUpdating recently. When trying to update field in an updating item I had the same exception as yours. My solution was to change event receiver from ItemUpdating to ItemUpdated. If you need strictly ItemUpdating event then I suggest to run code which refers to item modification in a separate thread.

Of course such solution have less control over item behavior and may lead to concurrent update issues.

Answer (score 0):

How Per wrote you, you don't need the SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges and a lock on you code.
I think you don't need a item.Update or SystemUpdate because you are in updateing.
If the document it's new you have the error because sharepoint doesn't find it.

Try to remove all the code that the guys are suggest to you and move the base.ItemUpdating(properties); at the end of function an remove item.Update() method.